# Return element of a list in new variable and remove it from the list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, popup

```
Table_id = ['43c776cc-dcfe-498e-9e0c-465e498c4509','fbcbdda3-e391-42f0-b139-c266c0bd564d','caa5ebb5- 
eee1-4261-8646-75139a22fa14']
    
naming= range(1,len(Table_id))
list_to_pop= Table_id.copy()
    
for i in range(len(Table_id)-1):
    if i in Table_id:
      print("Table_"+[naming[0]],i.pop())
      naming.pop(0)
```

---

The output I would like to have is something like the following:

```
Table_1 = 'caa5ebb5-eee1-4261-8646-75139a22fa14'
Table_2 = 'fbcbdda3-e391-42f0-b139-c266c0bd564d'
Table_3 = '43c776cc-dcfe-498e-9e0c-465e498c4509'
```

Any helps?

Comment: You want to have those variables defined as in python file?

Comment: I want to have element from my list in  variable having a different name according to the element from the list if I choose the first one, it is going to be called Table_1 then this element is removed from the list and we take the second one which is going to be called Table_2 and so on and at the end I should have no more element in the list called table_id

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range(len(Table_id) - 1)` assigns 0 and 1 to `i` not a list!
`i.pop()` should raise an exception!

if you want to remove `Table_id[i]` from `Table_id`, you can use `del Table_id[i]` and if you want to delete an item with unknown index, you can use `Table_id.remove(value)`

Edited:
If just printing items in list is important:

```
Table_id = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

for i, v in enumerate(Table_id):
    print(f'Table_{i + 1} : {v}')
Table_id.clear()
```

Comment: How can I have called variable and not printed results? I want to be able to call for instance Table_1 with the related value in a next code block

Comment: You should use dictionaries for this purpose: `Table_id = {'Table_1' : 'item1', 'Table_2' : 'item2', 'Table_3' = 'item3'}` and then to get `item1`: `print(Table_id['Table_1'])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option tho it would be easier to just use a dictionary:

```py
Table_id = ['43c776cc-dcfe-498e-9e0c-465e498c4509', 'fbcbdda3-e391-42f0-b139-c266c0bd564d', 'caa5ebb5- eee1-4261-8646-75139a22fa14']

to_file = ''
for index, item in enumerate(Table_id):
    to_file += f'table_{index + 1} = "{item}"\n'

with open('this_file.py') as file:
    data = file.read()

with open('this_file.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write(to_file + data)
```

this_file.py is the current file You are writing this code but as I said dictionaries probably would be better as the other answer suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic variables using globals() or locals() but its highly recommended not to. Instead make a dictionary with keys named as variable which you want. In this case you can use Table['Table_1'] as an alternative to variable 'Table_1'.

Also do not pop/remove the items in the same loop, do it after you are done processing the data in Table_id

```
Table_id = ['43c776cc-dcfe-498e-9e0c-465e498c4509','fbcbdda3-e391-42f0-b139-c266c0bd564d','caa5ebb5- eee1-4261-8646-75139a22fa14']

Table = {}
for index, elem in enumerate(Table_id):
    key = 'Table_'+str(index+1)
    Table[key] = elem

for item in Table.values():
    Table_id.remove(item)

print(Table)
print(Table_id)
# {'Table_1': '43c776cc-dcfe-498e-9e0c-465e498c4509', 'Table_2': 'fbcbdda3-e391-42f0-b139-c266c0bd564d', 'Table_3': 'caa5ebb5- eee1-4261-8646-75139a22fa14'}
# []
```